# Passing variables to $.ajax().done()

Tags: jquery, ajax, loops, promise, scoping

I'm lost. How might I pass a loop variable to an AJAX .done() call?

```
for (var i in obj) {
   $.ajax(/script/).done(function(data){ console.log(data); });
}
```

Obviously, if I were to do `console.log(i+' '+data)` *i* would return the very last key in the object `obj` on every single iteration. Documentation fails me.

Comment: I figure I could use `success`, but as I understand that is deprecated now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a closure (via a self executing function) to capture the value of `i` for each invocation of the loop like this:

```
for (var i in obj) {
    (function(index) {
        // you can use the variable "index" here instead of i
        $.ajax(/script/).done(function(data){ console.log(data); });
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: Closures are one concept I've always had a tough time understanding fully. Thanks @jfriend00, I'ma try that!

Comment: Yep, that worked. I could even do `obj[index]`. Thanks again!

Answer (score 20):

You can just create a custom field in the object that you send to $.ajax(), and it will be a field in `this` when the promise callback is made.

For example:

`$.ajax(
    { url: "https://localhost/whatever.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: JSON.stringify( object ),
      custom: i   //  creating a custom field named "custom"
    } ).done( function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { var index = this.custom; } );`

Comment: After 5 years, I have long since forgotten what even prompted this question. ;)

Comment: I needed to know how to do this for a recent project. So, when I figured it out, I tried to also relay the information to others who said that they wanted it...

Comment: This is better from jquery ajax asynchronous execution point of view, it clearly provide intended item/object reference when callback is executed latter in time.