# How to pass variable to ajax.done() inside a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

**I want to pass a variable to the .done() of my ajax call that happens inside a loop.** Here is my original code :

```html
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
    </head> 

    <body>
        <div class="list">
            <div class="item" id="item1" data-user-id="1"></div>
            <div class="item" id="item2" data-user-id="2"></div>
            <div class="item" id="item3" data-user-id="3"></div>
            <div class="item" id="item4" data-user-id="4"></div>        
        </div>
        <script>           
            $('.list').children(".item").toArray().forEach(
                item => {            
                    $item = $(item)
                    $id = $item.data("userId")
                    $itemID = $item.attr('id')
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
                        data: { "id": $id },                    
                    }).done(res => {    
                        console.log($itemID)
                    });
                }
            );         
        </script>    
    </body>
```

```html
    item4
    item4
    item4
    item4
```

when I expected to see (in any order):

```html
    item1
    item2
    item3
    item4
```

I found [Passing variables to $.ajax().done()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059219/passing-variables-to-ajax-done) but neither of the 2 solutions worked :

the first one using immediately invoked function expression:

```html
    .done(
        ((result) => {                        
            console.log(result)
            console.log($itemID)
        })(res)
    );
```

```html
    ReferenceError: res is not defined
```

the second one using a custom ajax parameter :

```html
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
        data: { "id": $id },
        custom: $itemID   
        // same results with custom: { customID: $itemID }             
    }).done(res => {                        
        console.log(res)
        console.log(this.cutsom)
        // same output with console.log($itemID)
        //                  console.log(this.$itemID)
    });
```

```html
    item4
    undefined
    item4
    undefined
    item4
    undefined
    item4
    undefined
```

I found other solutions that did not work either (mostly using the deprecated `success` property). If I missed an obvious answer, I'm sorry, I tried my best.

Comment: Don't use global variables! When you do `$itemID=somValue` it is the same as `window.$itemID =somValue` and will be overwritten every iterarion of the loop

Comment: I was experimenting in a codepen and i thought it didn't matter cause nobody would ever read this code... let this be a lesson i guess....

Comment: Can turn into a bad habit not declaring variables properly and run into side effects just like this one that are tricky to debug and not so obvious. Consider  it a good lesson !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a scope problem. You need to limit the scope of `$item`, `$id` and `$itemId` to your foreach function.

```
var $item = $(item);
var $id = $item.data("userId");
var $itemID = $item.attr('id');
```

Otherwise the last call of `$itemID = ...` holds your last id by the time your async  ajax function is finished

Comment: I feel so dumb, I forgot to add the ```let``` >.<'

Answer (score 0):

The best way to code something like you want, is to put your .ajax method inside a function like the following. That way, you'll define a scope to the variables.

```js
function req($id, $itemID) {
  $.ajax({
      url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
      data: { "id": $id },                    
  }).done(res => {    
      console.log($itemID)
  });
}

$('.list').children(".item").toArray().forEach(
    item => {            
        $item = $(item)
        $id = $item.data("userId")
        $itemID = $item.attr('id')
        req($id, $itemID);
    }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <div class="item" id="item1" data-user-id="1"></div>
  <div class="item" id="item2" data-user-id="2"></div>
  <div class="item" id="item3" data-user-id="3"></div>
  <div class="item" id="item4" data-user-id="4"></div>        
</div>
```

Comment: You are still using global variables which is the root of OP's issue. The added function creates a new closure but using the `forEach` closure properly with scoped variables  would also solve the issue

Comment: I do like the isolation of the ajax in its own function though, thank you !